# How extract data from line

Tags: php, arrays, reference, explode

Hello and thank´s for the help in advanced

**I want extract data globally from one line, but don´t get results, i put my code**

**Function read line data**

```
 function line_data($data)
    {
    $data_exp=explode(",",$data);
    
    foreach($data_exp as $data_end)
    {
    echo $data_end;
    }
    
    return $data_end;
    }
```

**Php Script Running**

```
$line_1="one,two,three,four";
$line_2=array($numbers);

$line_end="".$line_1.",".$line_2."";

line_data($line_end);
```

**line_1** have normal data, and **line_2** have one array and put all in one string called **line_end**, and process inside function for extract all values, normal values and values from array,but i can´t get works

**Sorry if don´t understand something English no native, thank´s**

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like [this](https://3v4l.org/FI4Hk)?

Comment: Yes more or less it´s the idea, but for examplei need only get values from array when in the loop foreach detect value it´s really arrray, explode search data by "," and only need when the data it´s array get all values from that array and no more, and agrupate all values in one only string for that array, for example get one,two,three,four, and finally when send $_POST with multiple select, recopilate all data from that array, in this case all data from $numbers